# OpenMP: Why are locks slower than the critical section?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp, critical-section

I'm testing simple locks and critical sections in OpenMP using a simple program as an example.
'Based on two vectors A and B (of length N), find the product of nonzero values A[i] * B[i]'.

My code:

```
const int N = 1000000;
const int R = 50;

void fill(vector<int>& vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        vec[i] = rand() % R;
    }
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    chrono::duration<int64_t, nano> time;

    vector <int> A(N);
    vector <int> B(N);
    fill(A);
    fill(B);

    int i = 0;
    unsigned long long int total = 1;

    cout << "\n\n* Locks: " << endl;
    total = 1;
    omp_lock_t lock;
    omp_init_lock(&lock);
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] + B[i] != 0) {
            omp_set_lock(&lock);
            total *= A[i] + B[i];
            omp_unset_lock(&lock);
        }
    }
    time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    omp_destroy_lock(&lock);
    cout << "\nResult Ai + Bi: " << total;
    cout << "\nTime: " << time.count() << " ns";


    cout << "\n\n* Critical section: " << endl;
    total = 1;
    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] + B[i] != 0) {
#pragma omp critical
            total *= A[i] + B[i];
        }
    }
    time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

    cout << "\nResult Ai + Bi: " << total;
    cout << "\nTime: " << time.count() << " ns";
}
```

I measured the time in nanoseconds and it turned out that the critical section works a little faster than the lock. Why, if they actually do the same thing?

Visual Studio 2022, Windows 11

Comment: Question zero: did you compile with compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, yes

Comment: Do you get the same result if you reverse the order of the loop? Frequency scaling and cache effect may play a role in the observed behaviour.

Comment: Another point: can you reproduce the problem with the Clang runtime using `/openmp:llvm` ?

Comment: All of these seem to be producing a result of 0, which tends to render the amount of time taken pretty close to irrelevant. If I reduce the array size so I can get a result that fits in an unsigned long long, it appears that (as expected) it's better to avoid either of those approaches, and use `reduction (*:total)` instead: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74411d147888ac9d

Comment: MSVC 17.3.5 using `/openmp` option: `Locks: 8.14408e+08±6.24387e+06 ns, Critical: 6.60584e+08±9.03817e+06 ns` -- so the runtimes are statistically different. Using `/openmp:llvm` flag `Locks:1.59346e+08±3.90749e+07 ns, Critical:1.48432e+08±3.08702e+07 ns` -- the runtimes are statistically the same.